# How to use protocol-buffers with autoconf/automake?

Tags: protocol-buffers, automake

Looking for a good example of autoconf and automake rules for building a project that uses protocol buffers, best way to add protoc to the build process?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### `configure.ac`

As far as the protobuf library goes, it uses `pkg-config`, so it's probably best to refer to it using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(PROTOBUF, protobuf >= 2.4.0)
AC_SUBST(PROTOBUF_LIBS)
AC_SUBST(PROTOBUF_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(PROTOBUF_VERSION)
```

And check for `protoc` command in the path. Here's a very basic check that it's in the path:

```
AC_CHECK_PROG([PROTOC], [protoc], [protoc])
AS_IF([test "x${PROTOC}" == "x"],
    [AC_MSG_ERROR([ProtoBuf compiler "protoc" not found.])])
```

Alternatively, allow the user to specify a different `protoc` with either `--with-protoc=/path/to/protoc` or using environment variable `PROTOC`:

```
# ProtoBuf compiler.
# First, specify with --with-protoc=/path/of/protoc.
# Or, specify with env variable PROTOC.
# If neither of the above, find it in the path.
#AC_MSG_CHECKING([for ProtoBuf compiler protoc])
AC_ARG_WITH([protoc],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-protoc=/path/of/protoc],
        [Location of the protocol buffers compiler protoc. Defaults to looking on path.])],
    [PROTOC="$withval"],
    [ AS_IF([test "x${PROTOC}" == "x"],
        [AC_PATH_PROG([PROTOC], [protoc], [no])])
    ]
)
#AC_MSG_RESULT([${PROTOC}])
AS_IF([test "${PROTOC}" == "no"], [AC_MSG_ERROR([ProtoBuf compiler "protoc" not found.])])
```

#### `Makefile.am`

Add a rule to build the `proto` files:

```
%.pb.cc %.pb.h: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) --proto_path=$(srcdir) --cpp_out=$(builddir) $^
```

Specify protobuf source files with `dist_noinst_DATA`. This is necessary to ensure they get bundled in a source distribution `.tar.gz` file made with `make dist`.

```
dist_noinst_DATA = whatever.proto
```

(Note: for newer versions of autoconf/automake, it may be necessary to use `@builddir@` instead of `$(builddir)`.)

Specify generated files with `nodist_` prefix and `$(builddir)` path:

```
nodist_myprog_SOURCES = $(builddir)/whatever.pb.cc $(builddir)/whatever.pb.h
```

And to clean them with `make clean`:

```
MOSTLYCLEANFILES = whatever.pb.cc whatever.pb.h
```

Use `BUILT_SOURCES` to handle dependency for built header files:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = whatever.pb.h
```

Your compiler flags may need to refer to the build directory to find the header file (to work in VPATH builds):

```
AM_CPPFLAGS += -I$(builddir)
```

Comment: The `AC_SUBST(PROTOBUF_*)`  are not needed if `autoconf >= 0.24` as explained in [section 3.2 of Autotools myths](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html)

Comment: Very nice, thank you! `nodist_myprog_SOURCES` needs to use `@builddir@/whatever.pb.cc` now.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work:

configure.ac:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([protobuf-libdir],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-protobuf-libdir=LIB_DIR],
        [location of the protocol buffers libraries, defaults to /usr/lib])],
    [PROTOBUF_LIBDIR="$withval"],
    [PROTOBUF_LIBDIR='/usr/lib'])
AC_SUBST([PROTOBUF_LIBDIR])

LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L$PROTOBUF_LIBDIR"

AC_CHECK_LIB([protobuf], [main], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find protobuf library])])

AC_ARG_WITH([protoc],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-protoc=PATH],
        [location of the protoc protocol buffer compiler binary, defaults to protoc])],
    [PROTOC="$withval"],
    [PROTOC='protoc'])
AC_SUBST([PROTOC])
```

Makefile.am:

```
%.pb.cc %.pb.h: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) --proto_path=$(dir $^) --cpp_out=$(dir $^) $^
```

And then add the .pb.cc files to SOURCES.

Comment: Does that `Makefile.am` rule work with VPATH builds (e.g. `mkdir build; cd build; ../configure; make`)? The output files should probably go in `$builddir` rather than in `$srcdir`.

Comment: With `$(dir $^)` in the `Makefile.am` rule, I get an error `Makefile.am:11: dir $^: non-POSIX variable name; Makefile.am:11: (probably a GNU make extension)`.